# how to navigate back to login page after successful register

Tags: android

```
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         if(v == buttonRegister){
            registerUser();
          }
     }
private void registerUser() {
    ?*some code here*/   
}
private void register(String name, String email, String password, String phone ) {
    String urlSuffix = "?name="+name+"&email="+email+"&password="+password+"&phone="+phone;
    class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog loading;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(SignUpActivity.this, "Please Wait",null, true, true);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String s = params[0];
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(REGISTER_URL+s);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String result;

                result = bufferedReader.readLine();

                return result;
            }catch(Exception e){
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    RegisterUser ru = new RegisterUser();
    ru.execute(urlSuffix);
}
```

Comment: i need go back login activity after the user has scucessfully registered else display some error

Answer (score 1):

```
If you moved from login activity to this screen then you can use:

 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            this.finish();


        }


Otherwise you can start new activity like :

@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));
            this.finish();

        }
```

Comment: if the user email id already exist means it should not navigate to login activity. it should be in the same signupactivity. if the user is new should navigate to login activity

Comment: can any one suggest this

Comment: @user000 Add condition before you start intent.

Comment: Check response of ``onPostExecute``, if is new user, you can ``startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));`` , else Show error about email exists.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on your REST API and what it is returning, if you can post the json result from API it can be of much help.
If it is returning message like "email already exists" then you can check if that string exists in the message, and do accordingly

Change your onPostExecute method to:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(s.has("email already exists")){
                //Show some error
            }else if(s.has("Registration successfull"))
            startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));
            this.finish();

        }
```

Comment: if($row > 0)
     {
                   echo 'email already exist';
                 }
  $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO register(`name`,`password`,`email`,`phone`) VALUES('".$_GET['name']."','".$_GET['password']."','".$_GET['email']."','".$_GET['phone']."')";
                 if($insert)
   {
      echo 'successfully registered';
   }

Comment: Post your json result please, not server side code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
 $name = $_GET['name'];
 $password = $_GET['password'];
 $email = $_GET['email'];
 $phone = $_GET['phone'];

 if($name == '' || $password == '' || $email == '' ||  $phone == '')
   {
     echo 'please fill all values';
       }
         else{
        $check =$db->query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE email='".$_GET['email']."'"; 
   $row=$check->num_rows;
        if($row > 0)
 {
               echo 'email already exist';
             }
       else
      { 
             $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO register(`name`,`password`,`email`,`phone`) VALUES('".$_GET['name']."','".$_GET['password']."','".$_GET['email']."','".$_GET['phone']."')";
             if($insert)
    {
  echo 'successfully registered';
```

}
       else
        {
              echo 'oops! Please try again!';
          }
               }
            }
        }
      else{
             echo "Error";
       }

Answer (score 0):

You should use single Activity with `LoginFragment` and `RegisterFragment`.
If user login from LoginFragment then he can directly go to new Activity.
If user select `Register` then you need to add the new Fragment on backstack and see if he completes registration. If user completes registration then you can just pop `backstack` and you land on `LoginPage`.

Just for Login and Registraion i will not suggest using two different activities when you can achieve same result using `1 Activity` and `2 Fragment.`